# database design (joining 3 tables together)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, join, database-design

My goal is to create a web app that show elections results from my country.

The data is the results for every candidates in every city for every election.

- An election has many candidates and many cities.
- A candidate has many elections and many cities.
- A city has many elections and many candidates.
  For the 2nd round of the last presidential election:

| City | inscrits | votants | exprime | candidate1 | score C1 | candidate2 | score C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dijon | 129000 | 100000 | 80000 | Macron | 50000 | Le Pen | 30000 |
| Lyon | 1000000 | 900000 | 750000 | Macron | 450000 | Le Pen | 300000 |

How can I join those 3 tables together?

Is it possible to create a join table between the three, like this?

```
  create_table "results", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "election_id", null: false
    t.integer "candidate_id", null: false
    t.integer "city_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["city_id"], name: "index_results_on_city_id"
    t.index ["candidate_id"], name: "index_results_on_candidate_id"
    t.index ["election_id"], name: "index_results_on_election_id"
  end
```

But in this case, where can I add the city infos for election? (Column 2, 3, 4 of my data example, i.e: in this city, for this election XXX people voted, XXX didn't vote.)

I came with this database schema:

[my database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnX4S.png)

This will not work because I will not be able to access the result of a candidate in a specific city for a specific election. It looks like there is no connection between cities and candidates.

Comment: Your `candidate_results` table should have an association to `city_results`, not `elections`. So for each `election`, a candidate will have multiple `city_results` and their final "score" will be the sum of the scores of their `city_results` for a given election

Comment: @AbM in theory you could calculate the results of a national election that way - but that would require a perfectly complete data set.

Comment: I would instead use tables for every level you need to represent for example `city_results`, `region_results`, `national_results` and fill them with data from a reputable source. I would avoid doing your own vote counting as any holes in your data will give incorrect results.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how/why you are 1st stuck/unsure at what step among which steps following what published presentation of what design method/process given what? [ask] [Help] Debug questions require a [mre].

Comment: Thanks @AbM and max. My data set is suppose to be 'perfectly complete' since it came from the government.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually tie these models together and record the data required you need a series of tables that record the election results at each level your interested in:

```ruby
# rails g model national_result candidate:belongs_to election:belongs_to votes:integer percentage:decimal
class NationalResult < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :candidate
  belongs_to :election
  delegate :name, to: :candidate,
                  prefix: true
end

# rails g model city_result candidate:belongs_to election:belongs_to votes:integer percentage:decimal
class CityResult < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :candidate
  belongs_to :election
  delegate :name, to: :candidate,
                  prefix: true
end
```

Instead of having C1 and C2 columns you should use one row per candidate instead to record their result. That will let you use the same table layout even if there are more then two candidates (like in a primary) and avoids the problem of figuring out which column a candidate is in. Use foreign keys and record the primary key instead of filling your table with duplicates of the names of the candidates which can easily become denormalized.

While you might naively think "But I don't need NationalResult, I can just sum up all the LocalResult's!" - that process would actually expose any problems in your data set and very likely be quite expensive. Get the data from a repubable source instead.

You can then create the `has_many` assocations on the other side:

```ruby
class Canditate < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :local_results
  has_many :national_results 
end

class Election < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :local_results
  has_many :national_results 
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :local_results
end
```

Keeping track of the number of eligable voters per election/city will most likely require another table.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser @max. I get my data in huge Excel files (more than 36k rows for each election) from an official government website, so I'm stuck with their presentation. They also publish the results for each level so I will also use these datas as you suggest. And I will create a new table for the number of voters since it's something important for the project.